# GitHub Actions workflow environment variables on organization level

Tags: github-actions

Is it possible to have environment variables on organization level for GitHub Actions? So something like organization secrets but just with environment variables.

Since we have a lot of repositories in our organization I would like to keep the runner version in a global environment variable and so when we decide to update the runner version we can simply change it in the environment settings instead of every workflow file.

**EDIT**
Variables are now supported on organization level. Here the docs
https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/variables

Comment: At the moment there's no other way to achieve this, except with organizational secrets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Posting this as I missed the EDIT section of the question and couldn't find the answer in the answers section.*

As [dulvui](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8794667/dulvui) states in the EDIT section of the question, this is supported since January 10th 2023 as [posted by Github](https://github.blog/changelog/2023-01-10-github-actions-support-for-configuration-variables-in-workflows/).

Specifically at https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/variables#creating-configuration-variables-for-an-organization, it states:

> You can create configuration variables for use across multiple workflows, and can define them at either the organization, repository, or environment level.

And the documentation specifically for the `organization` level: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/variables#creating-configuration-variables-for-an-organization

Answer (score 0):

You can put the value into the GitHub organization secret. Check the following link to get further details:
https://docs.github.com/en/codespaces/managing-codespaces-for-your-organization/managing-encrypted-secrets-for-your-repository-and-organization-for-codespaces#adding-secrets-for-an-organization

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).